Lithium ion vs LIPO battery which has more durability
I am trying to build a power bank and due to some asthetic reason, it is better to use lithium ion battery in the project, and also the casing is designed for lithium ion battery. now I want to make the product long lasting and hence I have searched on the internet which battery is more durable between LIPO and LI. The confusion is that some of the websites are saying LI has more durablity than LIPO while others are saying completely opposite. so the primary question I have here is:
among lipo and LI, which is more durable? by "durability" I mean which battery looses its charge storage capability fast? also which battery lasts longer before they completely die?
Note here that safety is not a concern here, also how heavy the battery that too does not matter

What you call a "LIPO" cell IS a Li-ion cell. So, asking "Lithium ion vs LIPO battery which has more durability" makes no sense as would be to ask "Humans vs men which has more durability". Inside, a pouch cell (which you call "LIPO") and a cylindrical cell use the same chemistries, the same materials, the same technology. The only difference is the packaging.
Yes, there are performance difference in various cells, but they are due to the chemistry, the technology, and the materials chosen. A given cylindrical cell may lasts longer than a given pouch cell, or vice-versa, depending on the brand and model. Specifically, any Li-ion cell (whether prismatic, cylindrical, or pouch) will last longer if it's not kept fully charged for long periods, is only charged when warm, is charged over 2 hours or longer, is discharged over 1 hour or longer with not peaks in current, is stored in cool temperatures. And, specifically for pouch cells, it is constrained against expansion.
Any website that says that a pouch cell lasts longer is written by someone who, like you, did not understand that a pouch cell is a Li-ion cell.
This table gives you the full picture:


To be precise lets assume a 5000mah power bank flat lipo and 26650 battery.

Allow me to correct you: "assume a 5000 mAh pouch cell and 26650 cylindrical cell. " Those are "cells", not "batteries". No one can answer that question without the required information: specs of each of those two cells, and precise information on how you intend to use them. Even whit that information, answering it requires a study that involves tests in a laboratory over prolonged periods = $$$.

thank you, I have never seen such explanation before, since i do not have expertise in battery chemistry I didnt knew these. all i want is to make the product durable, assuming two batteries(cells) has roughly same quality. Hope this time I have written it correcly. Cell: primitive power source, batteries: combination of cells.

If anyone else was confused or surprised (I certainly was), you can have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_battery_types basically all lithium batteries are Li-ion, and some of them are Li-Po.
I believe the misconception might come from the RC model world, where high C batteries are needed and they are advertised specifically as Li-Po, as opposed to Li-ions which do not have such high C capabilities (which I just learned is inexact information).

@Vladimir Cravero - "all lithium batteries are Li-ion, and some of them are Li-Po". Allow me correct a few errors there, if I may. 1) Lithium cells are not Li-ion cells: Lithium = not rechargeable, Li-ion = rechargeable. 2) Cells, not batteries. A battery is a collection of cells.. 3) There is no such thing on the market as Li-Po. Cells with a Lithium Polymer electrolyte never left the lab. What people call "Li-Po" are simply Li-ion cells using the LCO chemistry and in a pouch package.

@Vladimir Cravero - 4) "which do not have such high C capabilities". Not true. The current limitation in Li-ion cells is due to the technology used, not to the package used. So, there are Li-ion cylindrical cells that far surpass the current capability of many Li-ion pouch cells. 5) The "C-rating" is a marketing tool to sell more cells, regardless of the actual capabilities of a given cell.
